# How to disable SmartScreen for a specific .cmd file?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I recent made a group of .cmd files.
Called, 'Node.1.cmd' and 'Node.2.cmd', the files' purpose was supposed to open each other (in a chain-like process).
However, whenever I open one of the 2, it gives me a seriously annoying message:

### Windows Protected your PC.

Windows SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app may put your PC at risk.

I agree that this is a bit risky, but it was made for fun, not for destruction. It was just my way of showing people not to mess with my stuff. Not even did I set any LNK at my desktop to the file.

### Now, to get to the point, can I exclude this file from SmartScreen while keeping it on?

Because of this, I have problems opening it with a .vbs file


To be more specific, it opens but then automatically closes with a message:
The system cannot find the path specified.

Does windows SmartScreen encrypt the file or something like that? 
I scripted the following:

```
Titre = "What would you like to do ? RookieTEC9©" 
message = "What would you like to do ?"&vbcr&vbcr&_
"1 - Launch Project Node "&vbcr&_
"2 - Launch Golden Chrome"&vbcr&_
"3 - Launch An Application"&vbcr&_
"4 - Start Windows Update"&vbcr&_
"5 - Slide2Kill" 
Default ="1"
Question = InputBox(message,Titre,Default)
Select Case Question 
Case 1 Run(1)
Case 2 Run(2)
Case 3 Run(3)
Case 4 Run(4)
Case 5 Run(5)
end Select

Sub Run(var)
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
    Select Case var
    Case 1 WS.run("explorer.exe /e,C:\Users\Jeremi\OneDrive\Happy_files\Unsorted_Files\Project_Node.zip\Node.1.cmd")
    Case 2 ProcessNotNeeded()
    Case 3 LaunchApplication()
    Case 4 WindowsUpdate()
    Case 5 WS.run("SlideToShutDown.exe")
End select
End Sub 

Sub Kill(Process)
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Command = "cmd /c Taskkill /F /IM "&Process&""
Execution = Ws.Run(Command,0,False)
End Sub

Sub ProcessNotNeeded()
Titre = "Killing Process Not Needed RookieTEC9© "
message = "Type the Name of the process to be killed by this script"&vbcr&_
"Example To Kill The Internet Explorer Process You should type"&vbcr&_
"iexplore.exe"
Default ="iexplore.exe"
Question = InputBox(message,Titre,Default)
Kill(Question)
End Sub

Function CmdPrompt(sCmd)
Dim sCmdLine,oWS,nRes
set oWS = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sCmdLine = "cmd /c Start " & sCmd & ""
nRes = oWS.Run(sCmdLine,0,False)
CmdPrompt = nRes
End Function

Sub LaunchApplication()
Titre = "Launching an Application"
message = "Type the Name of the process to be Lanuched by this  script"&vbcr&_
"Example To Launch The Word Application You should type"&vbcr&_
"Winword.exe" 
Default ="Winword.exe"
Question = InputBox(message,Titre,Default)
CmdPrompt(Question)
End Sub

Sub WindowsUpdate()
Title = "Checking for Windows updates"
Msg = "Looking for a list of updates, So be Patient Thank you !"
Wait = "70" 'waiting 70 secondes to close the popup
Set Ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ws.Popup Msg,wait,Title,64

Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()        
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and    Type='Software'") 

If searchResult.Updates.Count <> 0 Then 'If updates were found
'so with this loop shows how you can list the title of each update that was found.
For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    ws.Popup update.Title,wait,Title,64
Next
End If
Ws.Run "wuauclt.exe /reportnow /detectnow",1,False
End Sub
```

Sorry for the long code!
To be 100% honest, I didn't create this from scratch, I just edited it.
I am new to VBS
However, if you have any questions on HTML or CSS, I may be able to answer it.
Please keep in mind that I am a 5th grader and only started coding this school year.

THX for your time and answer.
P.S.

Also, the file was in a zip. Does that effect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unblock these CMD files, it is explained [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/124367-open-file-security-warning-unblock-file.html)
Once unblocked you should be able to run it from the console and from your script.
I myself scripted a very long time in vbscript but now it is obsolete. Since you have 
just started to learn, I advise you to learn another scripting language like [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) which is fun to learn or if you want to go the 'only windows' way Powershell (shiver..)

Comment: Thank you! I will take your advise, but may continue VBS in the future. I have looked at Powershell, but that just isn't my style.